# Angular changedetection not working with subject

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-changedetection

I have a list of todo's which I need to update whenever a todo is added or finished. The UI updates perfectly without my subject, but when I want to use a subject (which gets a new value when the database has changed), it doesn't update.

```
//Initial loading of all the todos
    this.todos = await this.todoService.getTodos(this.locationId);

//Reloading todos whenever the database has changed.
//This subscription causes the UI to not refresh after deleting a todo or adding a new one.
    this.subscription = this.dbService.subject.subscribe(async () => {
      console.log('changes todo');
      this.todos = await this.todoService.getTodos(this.locationId);
      this.cd.markForCheck();
    });
  }

  ionViewWillLeave() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

getTodos()

```
  async getTodos(
    locationId: string,
    limit?: number,
    done?: boolean
  ): Promise<any> {
    let selector = {};
    if (done !== false) {
      selector = {
        Type: 'remark',
        IsTodo: true,
        Shop: locationId,
      };
    }

    if (done == false) {
      selector = {
        Type: 'remark',
        IsTodo: true,
        Shop: locationId,
        Done_date: false,
      };
    }

    selector['Delivery_date'] = {
      $exists: true,
    };

    const options = {
      selector,
      fields: [
        'Title',
        'Delivery_date',
        '_id',
        '_rev',
        'IsPriority',
        'ResponsibleUser',
        'Comment',
        'Done_date',
        'Shop',
        'Shop_name',
      ],
      limit,
      // sort: [{ Type: 'desc' }, { Delivery_date: 'desc' }],
    };
    const result = await this.dbService.find(options);
    return result.docs;
  }
```

Edit: Added getTodos()

Comment: IMO mixing promises and observables in Angular causes unwanted issues like these. It'd be better to convert promises to observables (or vice-versa). It could be done if you'd provide more info. For a start, how is the `getTodos(this.locationId)` defined?

Comment: I've added the getTodos() method in my edit

Comment: @MichaelD thing is, I use the same technique to refresh my dashboard and for some reason it DOES work there.. Can't figure out why not on this page though